# Blinking LED code at a particular frequency

Tags: c, embedded, device-driver

I wrote a function for interacting with my `PIC16F1788`. The code sends pulses out the `RC4` port at a specific frequency, to make an LED blink according to that frequency. So the LED will blink faster or slower depending on the magnitude of the frequency. I decided to take a blinking code and vary the delay time according to my input frequency as follows.

```
void blink(int frequency){
/* starts the LED blinking at a particular frequency */

while(1)
{ 
 PORTCbits.RC4=0XFF;  // RC4 on
 __delay_ms(1000/frequency);   // time in ms dealing with frequency values in kHz
 PORTcbits.RC4=0X00;   // RC4 off
 __delay_ms(1000/frequency);   // time in ms dealing with frequency values in kHz
}



}
```

would this code work, is this a good idea ,and is there anyway that I could improve it?

Comment: I find this an odd question. It resembles the sample code on page 7 of [this tutorial](https://www.pantechsolutions.net/media/k2/attachments/led_Interfacing_With_PIC16F877A_Primer.pdf), except you've changed some stuff. Yet you haven't included the relevant struct definitions to make that change meaningful. Furthermore, your inconsistent capitalization is suspicious — probably wrong — so I'm putting this question on hold as probably broken code. Please add some relevant detail to make it a fully working program.

Comment: what I am trying to do is to blink an LED at pin RC4 depending on the input frequency of a signal input. so as the signal frequency changes the LED's will blink faster or slower. This is just a beginners code as I am trying to learn how to code PIC's thanks.

Comment: What you wrote is an infinite loop, so the frequency will never get a chance to change. Code Review is the place to review working, almost-finished code. If you need help getting something working, Stack Overflow or [electronics.se] would be the place to ask.

Answer (score 4):

Your code:

```
void fault_blink(int frequency){
/* starts the LED blinking at a particular frequency */

while(1)
{ 
 PORTCbits.RC4=0XFF;  // RC4 on
 __delay_ms(1000/frequency);   // time in ms dealing with frequency values in kHz
 PORTcbits.RC4=0X00;   // RC4 off
 __delay_ms(1000/frequency);   // time in ms dealing with frequency values in kHz
}
}
```

## Indentation

The body of the `fault_blink` function should be indented, along with the body of the `while` loop.

The code now:

```
void fault_blink(int frequency){
/* starts the LED blinking at a particular frequency */

    while(1)
    { 
         PORTCbits.RC4=0XFF;  // RC4 on
         __delay_ms(1000/frequency);   // time in ms dealing with frequency values in kHz
         PORTcbits.RC4=0X00;   // RC4 off
         __delay_ms(1000/frequency);   // time in ms dealing with frequency values in kHz
    }
}
```

## Spacing

To enhance readability, there should be spaces around arithmetic operators and `=` signs.

The code now:

```
void fault_blink(int frequency) {
/* starts the LED blinking at a particular frequency */

    while(1)
    { 
         PORTCbits.RC4 = 0XFF;  // RC4 on
         __delay_ms(1000 / frequency);   // time in ms dealing with frequency values in kHz
         PORTcbits.RC4 = 0X00;   // RC4 off
         __delay_ms(1000 / frequency);   // time in ms dealing with frequency values in kHz
    }
}
```

## 0X vs 0x

This isn't the biggest thing, but most people have a lower-case 'x' when defining a number as a hexadecimal number.

The code now:

```
void fault_blink(int frequency) {
/* starts the LED blinking at a particular frequency */

    while(1)
    { 
         PORTCbits.RC4 = 0xFF;  // RC4 on
         __delay_ms(1000 / frequency);   // time in ms dealing with frequency values in kHz
         PORTcbits.RC4 = 0x00;   // RC4 off
         __delay_ms(1000 / frequency);   // time in ms dealing with frequency values in kHz
    }
}
```

## Unnecessary comments

Don't repeat your comments; especially when the original comment is very near.

In this part of your code:

```
PORTCbits.RC4=0XFF;  // RC4 on
__delay_ms(1000/frequency);   // time in ms dealing with frequency values in kHz
PORTcbits.RC4=0X00;   // RC4 off
__delay_ms(1000/frequency);   // time in ms dealing with frequency values in kHz
```

You can remove the comment on the second `__delay_ms` call as the comment is identical to the call right above it.